# What is the proper way to remove a reference using the .NET 4 Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have an instance of `TPM_PROJECTVERSION` called `projectVersion`, which has a property called `TPM_USER5` which is of type `TPM_USER`.  A `TPM_PROJECTVERSION` can have zero or one `TPM_USER5` references (Sorry, I didn't come up with these names.)

When the user clicks a *Delete* button, I want to remove this reference, thus setting the column in the database to null.  I've tried the following:

```
projectVersion.TPM_USER5 = null;
```

However, when I call `context.SaveChanges()`, the column is not updated and nothing happens.  Under the debugger, I can see that `projectVersion.TPM_USER5` is indeed null, and I also see that `projectVersion.TPM_USER5Reference.IsLoaded` is true.  I've also tried:

```
context.DeleteObject(projectVersion.TPM_USER5);
```

If I do this, when I call `context.SaveChanges()`, I get the exception:

> {"ORA-02292: integrity constraint
>   (TPMDBO.TPM_PROJECTCHANGES_TPM_US_FK1) violated - child record found"}

I'd be happy to post more information about the entity mappings, but not sure exactly what's relevant.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly thus you removing only navigation property (TPM_USER5). Try set primitive property (TPM_USER5ID? - probably your db column name) to null.

Each navigation property must have relevant primitive property (not POCO entities) and you can use both to associate user to TPM_USER5 (primitive property - set id, navigation property - set reference).

Comment: I don't think there *is* a primitive representation of `TPM_USER5`.  It's a reference to a `TPM_USER` entity.  I could set `TPM_USER5.USERID` but it's a decimal, so not nullable.

Comment: Nevermind, you're 100% right.  `TPM_USER5` is actually a relationship based on a foreign key constraint, there's an actual property (Of type `Decimal?`) with a completely different name.  Setting *that* to null works great.

Comment: Yes, I guessed the name by navigation property name... I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Yes - Whoever originally wrote this code just used all the defaults from the "Import from Database" wizard, so none of the names make any sense (there's like TPM_USER1 - TPM_USER7 that map to who knows what)